# Interacting with UI not generated by your app with wix/detox

Tags: android, react-native, android-espresso, android-uiautomator, detox

I am running UI Tests on Android with Wix's Detox for a React Native project. The library works very well but struggles/cannot handle system dialogs or other views not owned by the instrumented app under test. Here is an annoying location accuracy pop-up from Google Play Services to illustrate;

[image]

I am thinking of rewriting the fledgling suite in Kotlin to gain access to the Android `UiAutomator` APIs that would allow me to locate any arbitrary view but wanted to check here if there was something else I can do with Detox to dismiss/accept these dialogs.

#### Things I have tried (and failed to get working)

1. Running on an emulator without play services. Failed owing to heavy use of Firebase stopping app init owing to missing play services.
2. Locate the backing ReactView and ask to tap arbitrarily on the screen where I know the OK button is at; *c.f.* `tapAtPoint({x:, y:})`
3. Revoke draw overlay permission to `com.google.gms`. Was never going to work in hindsight
4. Try to `device.pressBack()` *at the right time* to dismiss it without answering.

#### Things that did work

- Writing the test again in Kotlin and accessing the `UiDevice` and `UiSelector` APIs.
- Avoiding as many system generated pop-ups as possible using permission granting rules (config in `launchApp` in `detox`)

I would like to stay in detox land...perhaps I need to up my JavaScript game and submit a PR to the repo? I must admit, it is a very complex library...would need some help but willingly if a `wix/detox`-er gets in touch.

Comment: Thinking about it some more now I can see that the pop-up has focus...wondering whether I can dispatch ADB commands to tab, followed by a command to "enter". Detox for Android would be flexible if the `ADB()` object was exposed but perhaps that's against the ethos of the library...re: `DeviceDriver` abstraction. The iOS equivalent would be something like `xcrun`?